# How to find Anti virus version number in the Windows 7 and higher OS using WMI

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, wmi

For the Vista and post Vista OS the Windows WMI provides below properties:

- displayName
- instanceGuid
- pathToSignedProductExe
- pathToSignedReportingExe
- productState

There is no property defined to retrieve the version number. Where as in Win XP there is a property named "versionNumber" which retrieves the version number.

Do we have any way to get the version number of all the installed AV on Windows 7 OS using WMI?
Or is there any workaround to get the version number?

Comment: Sounds like you just have to resort to `GetFileVersionInfo()` and `VerQueryValue()` if you have the path to the AV's exe file.

Comment: Years ago, I had a similar task to extract the details of the PC's security software.(FWIW, we only needed the product name and to detect if it was enabled).  I basically wound up consulting this site: http://neophob.com/2010/03/wmi-query-windows-securitycenter2/  It looks like you are right, it doesn't provide for version number any more.

Remy is likely steering your correctly..  Given that there are a well known defined set of security products (AVG, Norton, Symatec, Mcafee, etc...), you could probably just scan for each binary in the products well known install path.